# what does this template do?

Tags: c++, templates, llvm

In the llvm source code `llvm/IR/PassManager.h` has this template (comments have been deleted for brevity):

```
struct alignas(8) AnalysisKey {};
struct alignas(8) AnalysisSetKey {};
template <typename IRUnitT> class AllAnalysesOn {
public:
  static AnalysisSetKey *ID() { return &SetKey; }

private:
  static AnalysisSetKey SetKey;
};

template <typename IRUnitT> AnalysisSetKey AllAnalysesOn<IRUnitT>::SetKey;
```

**edit:** I'm confused only about this: `template <typename IRUnitT> AnalysisSetKey AllAnalysesOn<IRUnitT>::SetKey;`

I'm familiar with using a template for a class or a function. The above usage appears very different. Instead of the template definition being followed by a class or a function, it's followed by a struct and then a class member variable. Any insight into what this does or why it is written this way would be appreciated.

Comment: It creates a class template calls AllAnalysesOn, which has a static method which ...... and a static variable which ....... and then also defines the variable....

Comment: A struct is a class.

Comment: The only difference between struct and class in C++ is whether things before the first `public:`/`protected:`/`private:` are private (class) or public (struct).

Comment: @arnt thanks, understood. I believe the comments about the struct vs class were provided at a time when I hadn't indicated which template i was confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose it was not a template and we don't care about alignment, then it would look like this:

```
struct AnalysisKey {};
struct AnalysisSetKey {};

class AllAnalysesOn {
public:
  static AnalysisSetKey *ID() { return &SetKey; }    
private:
  static AnalysisSetKey SetKey;
};

AnalysisSetKey AllAnalysesOn::SetKey;
```

The last line is the definition of the static member `SetKey`.

Comment: Thank you! thanks to you and foragerDev I have a good starting point for reasoning about the code.

Answer (score 2):

`SetKey` is a static data member so in this line

```
template <typename IRUnitT> AnalysisSetKey AllAnalysesOn<IRUnitT>::SetKey;
```

You are providing its definition of that variable so that memory can be allocated to static variable when this template is used.

If you are using C++17 this line could be written as:

```
static inline AnalysisSetKey SetKey;
```

Then you do need to write the line you are getting hard time to understand.

Comment: thank you! I remember reading something about static variables being different for template classes. This makes sense. I assume the variable is initialized using the default constructor?

Comment: yes it is initialized using default constructor.